# Is there more concise way to say "tomorrow morning" than "mañana por la mañana"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, tiempo

I am a designer, working on a weather forecast layout which will support Spanish translations.

Is there a shorter way to say "Tomorrow Morning" than "**mañana por la mañana**"?

I have many different constraints on the available width of the text and I need it to fit on one line. I am currently shrinking the text size considerably to make it fit these constraints.

I would love to know if there's an alternative way of expressing the same thing.

¡Gracias!

[image]

Comment: En español no hay una abreviatura válida y de uso común para la palabra **mañana**

Comment: Su problema de restricción de espacio es muy común cuando de va a traducir del inglés al español; el inglés es más "conciso" en muchas expresiones vs sus equivalentes en español, para ir no más lejos "we" del inglés es español es "nosotros" y ya hay un cambio de 2 letras a 8 letras!

Comment: ¿Es muy complicado usar 2 líneas de texto para este caso?

Comment: Mañana al amanecer

Comment: @jessegavin you might not understand what alvalongo's saying, but it's the first of two potential options: "is it very complicated to use two lines of text in this case?". This is one thing that would work, and you'd need to do if for the last box as well: "Mañana por la tarde". There's a good reason why none of the small number of weather apps I just randomly sampled in the last two minutes use text, and use either numbers or iconography to convey this information. If you forsee that more languages will need to be supported in the future, then dropping the text would make your life easier.

Comment: @jessegavin Friends speaking via instant message may shorten "mañana" to "mñ", but that's _very_ informal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If  abbreviating (to **mañ.**) is something unwanted, then instead of what you have

> **Mañana por la mañana**

You'll gain 2 spaces with

> **Mañana *a la* mañana**

Or even a 4 char gain, writing

> **Mañana temprano**

The concise way you need may be also achieved  using **a.m..**, the latin *ante meridiem for "antes del mediodía", before noon)

> **Mañana [a.m.](https://culturizando.com/gramatica-la-forma-correcta-de-escribir/)** (formally [correct](https://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/abreviaturas)), or
>
> **Mañana AM**

Now if in forecast you refer to [morning](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+morning&oq=define+morning) as ***[dawn](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+dawn&oq=define+dawn)*** or ***early morning*** in Spanish you could gain 6 or 5 characters saying

> **[Alba](https://dle.rae.es/?id=1XoeWk0) mañana**

Or, preferably (as grammatically correct)

> **Mañana al alba**

Comment: Esto es increíblemente útil. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: i think Mañana temprano is my favorite and the one I use the most.

Comment: Para nativos españoles cualquiera de estas variantes suena un poco rara. Mañana temprano quizá un poco menos, pero desde luego no tan corriente como "mañana por la mañana". De hecho mañana por la mañana es un periodo de tiempo que comprede hasta las doce del siguiente día, mientras que mañana temprano se entiende que no puede extenderse tanto.

Comment: I wouldn't feel `Mañana al alba` as something _natural_ at all, even if it is correct.

Comment: @julodnik: comparto, pero también "mañana por la mañana" suena raro en algunos lugares, donde se dice "mañana a la mañana".

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to post this as an answer, but please don't take it seriously because nobody will understand this, and you already have [a good answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31828/12637). The most concise way to write "mañana por la mañana" in Spanish is probably ***cras prima***.

> **[cras](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BCPZhOq)**
>
> 1. adv. dem. desus. mañana.
>
> **[prima](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UBQk8bX)**
>
> 13. f. Una de las siete horas canónicas, que se canta a primera hora de la mañana, después de laudes.
> 14. f. Primera de las cuatro partes iguales en que dividían los romanos el día artificial, y que comprendía desde el principio de la primera hora temporal, a la salida del sol, hasta el fin de la tercera, a media mañana.

So, *cras* is an obsolete way of saying *tomorrow* in Spanish, and *prima* refers to the first hour in the morning just after the down. But I am very much afraid that *cras prima* is ungrammatical, nonetheless.

I'm too much tempted to add the [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) tag to this question... :-D

Now for a more serious answer, I would write just ***amanecer*** or, using a shorter but somewhat poetic-ish form, ***al alba***. You don't need to write *mañana* because the user will see that bit of information between the ones corresponding to *esta noche* and *mañana*, so the user will understand that *amanecer* refers to the next down between tonight and tomorrow.

Comment: Gracias por compartir esto

Comment: a veces quisiera que cras fuera rescatable, luego recuerdo lo complicado de usar que es y se me pasa.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de haber entendido bien el significado de *prima*? Fíjate en *que se canta*. Las horas canónicas son horas en el sentido 10 del RAE: oraciones.

Comment: @PeterTaylor interesante. Yo tenía entendido que esas horas canónicas eran momentos específicos del día en los que tenían lugar determinadas oraciones, pero como se hacían siempre a la misma hora servía para saber en qué momento del día te encontrabas. Luego "prima" podría indicar "la hora a la que se reza la prima". Pero igual me equivoco, podría ser una pregunta interesante.

Comment: Bueno, de todas formas resulta que podrías usar *prima* en su acepción 14.

Comment: @PeterTaylor bien visto, lo añado.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión "**mañana en la mañana**" o "**mañana por la mañana**" son ambas correctas y no dan lugar a confusión. 
Lo que pasa es que la palabra "**mañana**" se está usando simultáneamente con 2 significados diferentes:
Por un lado, el primer "**mañana**" se refiere al siguiente día.
Y por otro lado el segundo "**mañana**" se refiere a una de las divisiones que tiene un día:

- madrugada
- mañana
- mediodía
- tarde
- noche
- medianoche

Comment: Fíjate que no se está preguntando por qué usamos la palabra _mañana_ dos veces con distintos significados. Se pregunta si hay alguna forma más corta de expresar lo mismo, dado que el texto "mañana por la mañana" no cabe correctamente en el espacio designado a tal efecto.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using "madrugada" or "de madrugada"?

> [madrugada](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Nqwq5nq)
>
> 1. f. amanecer (‖ tiempo durante el cual amanece).
> 2. f. Tiempo posterior a la medianoche y anterior al amanecer.
>
> de madrugada
>
> 1. loc. adv. Al amanecer, muy de mañana.

It will abide your width constraints, since it would not need that much real state than "mañana". User's won't find it difficult to understand, given the visual aid, that it's referring to the next day.

So by using "madrugada" you can convey "early next morning" in your app.

You could also use "Al amanecer"  or "[amanecer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2DDSavq%7C2DDkwWT)" since it conveys

> Empezar a aparecer la luz del día

Comment: Habitualmente decir "en la madrugada" se entiende ese periodo de tiempo después de media noche y justo antes del amanecer. y **amanecer" es solo ese corte instante en que amanece. Claro que esto puede cambiar en otras regiones hispanoahablantes sobre todo si son más evidentes las 4 estaciones como en Argentina o Chile.